# Any good terminal software which has split window support?

Tags: terminal, split-window

I would like to start terminal window via shell script with 2 splits opened in same window. One should do ssh and other one should change dir when opening. It needs to accept commands to be passed. (something similar to gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile). I'm looking for split window with profile and commands to execute while starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tmux` and `screen` terminal multiplexers are often used for this.

```
session=$RANDOM
tmux new-session -s "$session" -d "ssh foohost"
tmux split-window -t "$session:0"
tmux send-keys -t "$session:0.1" "cd workdir" "Enter"
tmux attach -t "$session"
```

```
session=screen-$RANDOM
screen -dmS "$session"
screen -S "$session" -X ...I gave up.
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer gave me an idea to achieve via xsendkeys. 

terminator -m &
sleep 1
xsendkeys control+shift+e
xvkbd -xsendevent -text "ssh -X $pool_machine\r"
xvkbd -xsendevent -text "cd $sb_dir/src\r"
xsendkeys control+shift+p
xvkbd -xsendevent -text "cd $choosen/src\r"

pool machine is where i need to compile and local machine i run emacs to edit. I like terminator better because i have zoom and hide other windows and bring it when its needed.

Comment: i started using tmux recently. it simply rocks.